# Careers site advertisement should use comments

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

In the following piece of code

[image: stackoverflow jobs ad]

The text on line 39 should be using comments: `// A career site that's...`

Comment: Add a space between `//` and `A` and shipit.

Comment: Seriously, the discussions we have on meta. :)

Comment: is that a curly quote

Comment: @KevinB I think that is JavaScript object.

Comment: Should probably be: `{"flexibleHours": true, "companyCulture": 100}`. Too many bugs out there, I prefer to stay here then.

Comment: whoa whoa whoa, no quoting js object keys if not necessary

Comment: @KevinB "*Yeah, I probably downvoted your post. "* - Thug programmer life.

Comment: @MarounMaroun today I learned that you can have italic emojis. Weird.

Comment: @shadow Not all people have straight face.

Comment: @mega6382 You think this is bad, I'm almost certain it is a *duplicate*. :-) Someone previously made the same suggestion, the ad was fixed, and then showing this version was a regression. Don't have time to hunt for the other question at the moment, though.

Comment: @CodyGray I have found the duplicate.

Comment: Real developers don't add comments, just bored one's

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct! We mistakenly had an old and incorrect version of the ad running for a bit today. This has been updated now.